# Flutter boot receiver

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to make a practice app using flutter. Is there a way to schedule task when the phone has been rebooted via boot receiver? I've been searching for it but I couldn't find an example where I could call a method from flutter and be called via boot receiver on native android?

Thanks